# Flutter Native Splash is not showing the correct image

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.3 as following to change the app icon and it is working perfectly

```
flutter_icons:
 android: "launcher_icon"
 ios: true
 image_path: "assets/logo.png"
```

now I want to use flutter_native_splash: ^2.1.6 to adjust my splash screen.
I used the following:

pubspec:

```
 flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#42a5f5"
  image: assets/launch_image.png
  android: true
  ios: true
```

Main.dart:

```
 void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
 await Firebase.initializeApp();
 runApp(const MyApp());
 }
```

problem is application always display the flutter_launcher_icon (logo.png) as splash screen, not the flutter_native_splash one (launcher_image). where is the problem?

Note: I removed icon luncher package. now it is using default Flutter icon as Splah icon! ..
I checked res directoy, I can find my correct image listed in new folders Dwaralble-hdpi .. etc with name of SPLASH. but it is not effective at all.

Answer (score 16):

##### This is most likely because you're using Android 12.

From the *flutter_native_splash* [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash):

> Android 12 handles the splash screen differently than previous
> versions. Please visit https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen. Following are Android 12 specific parameter.
>
> ```
> android_12:
> # The image parameter sets the splash screen icon image. If this parameter is not specified,
> # the app's launcher icon will be used instead.
> ```

So the problem is you need to set the android_12 parameter aswell as the image parameter, and then also set an image parameter inside. Like so:

*pubspec.yaml*:

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#42a5f5"
  image: assets/launch_image.png
  android_12: 
    image: assets/launch_image.png
  android: true
  ios: true
```

Assuming you have your path pointing to the right image file, it should now correctly display in the center of the screen.

Comment: Hello, it is actually working probably on Andriod 12 the problem is with android 9! can't find the problem

Comment: Sorry didn't make it clear. the current problem is shown the correct picture but with full screen. tried disable full screen paramater and gravity paramater, but didn't work

Comment: Oh, I see. So you got the correct path to your image then, that's good.
As I understand it, `fullscreen` is just to expand the current splash screen to cover the notification bar or not, so it makes sense as to why it wouldn't work.
If it's displaying just the image across the whole screen maybe you're using `background_image` instead of the `image` parameter? That's my best guess anyway.