# The flutter native splash icon isn't correct in Android 12

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to crop & extract the logo resided in the left and make it the splash screen icon in flutter using the flutter_native_splash package but every time I get it blurry, small, or doesn't fit in the required diameter. **The problem is in Android 12**. May I get help, please?

[image]

Comment: Can you add answer for these questions, that would help me understand better.

Are you running on Android? Is it Android 12? Did you do the Android 12 related parts in the package description? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74640474/9779791

Comment: Yes, it's really in Android 12, but I forgot to mention this. I edited the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Native Splash is not showing the correct image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72868129/flutter-native-splash-is-not-showing-the-correct-image)

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: Did you apply the parts related to the Android 12 from the package readme and from the SO link I've shared? Android 12's splash screen is working differently than the previous versions: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

I'd suggest just use the logo part(part with car, without autohub) or put this version of logo in a circle so it doesn't get cropped.

Comment: Yes. The problem is in the image size/resolution/quality itself. So, it gets blurry or corrupted. That's what I need help with.